# how to get the anonymous backing field name of an auto-implemented properties

Tags: c#

Not a full expert in C# here. Sorry in advance if this is a very common question.

consider the following property.

```
public bool IsOn{ get;set; }
```

above getter/setter property has anonymous backing field according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties

Is there a way for me to see what this "anonymous backing field" name is so that I can expand the setter without adding extra code. All I want to do is log the content of the values that's getting set to in a dll where this code exist. For example,

```
public bool IsOn
{ 
   get;
   set
   {
      Log(value);
      "field name generated by c#" = value;
   }
}
```

Or do I have to create a field manually every time I want to see what the value is being set to? if so it seems like a very unproductive approach to have them used when we consider about usability. Mind you this is only one of the setters I want to log out. there are many more needs logging on this specific dll

Comment: I think you have already answered your question

Comment: If you want to add logic, create your own backing field. The backing field the compiler generates is the same name as the property but camel case and has an `_` at the beginning. For your property it would be `_isOn`. You can see it using reflection, but there's no way (in base C#) to get when the setter is called beyond putting your own logic in the setter, in which case it's no longer an auto property and you're forced to make your own backing field if you want to store the value somewhere. The ways that do exist to do this at runtime are a great deal more complicated to implement.

Comment: For a bit more context, when you compile, `get` and `set` turn into methods that get called when you get or set the property respectively. In base C# you can't determine when a method gets called or what is passed to it without adding logic to the method itself. There are ways to do this with libraries, but again, they are a lot more complicated to implement. Just use your own backing field.

Comment: "*Or do I have to create a field manually*" - or you can let Visual Studio do it, just put the cursor on the property and click the light bowl in the margin.

Comment: FYI: "_Is there a way for me to see what this "anonymous backing field" name_" Yes, through reflection, for example. Or by inspecting the IL code of the compiled program/assembly, or decompiling it with the help of ILSpy, for example. But then you will realize that the anonymous backing field has a name that is not valid in C# syntax, hence even if you can know its name you still can't use it directly in C# source code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Auto-Implemented Property is a property that has the default get- and set-accessors. If you have to add logic to them, you have to create a usual property with a backing field:

```
private bool _IsOn;

public bool IsOn
{ 
   get { return _IsOn; }
   set
   {
      Log(value);
      _IsOn = value;
   }
}
```

However, a property that is logging somewhere is not a real property anymore, that's a heavy side-effect in my opinion. I would make it a method:

```
private bool _isActive = false;

public void ChangeState(bool active)
{
      Log(active);
    _isActive = active;
}

public bool IsActivated => _isActive;
```

Comment: Yea I wanted to avoid creating extra fields on an existing code if it was possible. but seems like there is no work around. thank you for clarifying in detail.